# Inserting NULL in python is giving an error

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-python, mysql-connector-python

I am trying to insert a null value via python and mysql connector.

```
update_query = ''' update people.names set fname=%s, lname=%s,address=%s where person_id = %s;'''
params = ['Bob', 'Jones', None, 507]
mysql_db.update_statement(update_query,params)
```

Gives the following error.

```
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 1536, in cmd_stmt_execute
result = self._handle_binary_result(packet)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 1475, in _handle_binary_result
raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1210 (HY000): Incorrect arguments to mysqld_stmt_execute
```

I have also tried `params = ['Bob', 'Jones', 'Null', 507]` But the `'Null'` is a string and this is not what I need.  I am trying to add `NULL` as `NULL` not as a string.

Comment: Try `["Bob", "Jones", None, "507"]`.

Comment: Same error as last time

Answer (score 0):

This isn't technically correct but it works for me.  `["bob","jones","",507]`when retrieving from the database python will recognise it at `None` which is `Null`.  However in mysql it is an empty string.